# Get current Outlook Window as Form

Tags: vb.net, outlook, outlook-addin

How can I get the Outlook windows from which is the Ribbon button is called as `Form` in vb.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All callbacks (e.g. button click event handlers) receive `IRibbonControl` as the parameter. `IRibbonControl.Context` property can be cast to either `Inspector` or `Explorer` object depending on where the button is hosted.

Comment: Thansk for your comment, What I try to archive is to get the location and size the Windows from which the button is called

Comment: Both Explorer and Inspector objects expose the Top, Left, Height, Width properties.Take a look at these objects with OutlookSpy.